# set field equal to method's parameter in java

Tags: java, methods, field

So I have code that looks like this:

```
public class CLASSNAME {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public METHODNAME(String testName, int testAge) {
        //does something
    }

    public ANOTHERMETHOD() {
        //does something else
    }
}
```

I have testName and testAge declared in another class, but I need to access them in my fields so I can use them in other methods. Right now I can only access testAge and testName in the METHODNAME method.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add *getters* and *setters* (also called *accessors* and *mutators*). For `Example`,

```
public class Example {
    public Example(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Then you can modify (or retrieve) the value(s) from an *instance* of the class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inheritance here. `Parent class` have some method. You will extend child class to parent class. And you will get all in `child class` from `parent class.`

Parent class need to have `getter/setter` also.

There is a complete example: Follow this

// A class to display the attributes of the vehicle

```
class Vehicle {
   String color;
   private int speed;
   private int size;
   public int getSize() {
      return size;
   }
   public int getSpeed() {
      return speed;
   }
   public void setSize(int i) {
      size = i;
   }
   public void setSpeed(int i) {
      speed = i;
   }
}

// A subclass which extends for vehicle
class Car extends Vehicle {
   int CC;
   int gears;
   int color;
   void attributescar() {
       // Error due to access violation
      // System.out.println("Speed of Car : " + speed); 
      // Error due to access violation
      //System.out.println("Size of Car : " + size); 
   }
}
public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     Car b1 = new Car();
     // the subclass can inherit 'color' member of the superclass
     b1.color = 500; 
     b1.setSpeed(200) ;
     b1.setSize(22);
     b1.CC = 1000;
     b1.gears = 5;
     // The subclass refers to the members of the superclass
     System.out.println("Color of Car : " + b1.color);
     System.out.println("Speed of Car : " + b1.getSpeed());
     System.out.println("Size of Car : " + b1.getSize());
     System.out.println("CC of Car : " + b1.CC);
     System.out.println("No of gears of Car : " + b1.gears);
  }
}
```

Resource Link: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/inheritance-in-java/